# string returned from page methods is html text, can not get return to display in the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pagemethods

In my application I am able to use pagemethods to call server side functions from the client side. This works no problem. Where I am confused is with the return from the server side function. I am returning a string to the client side (html text) which should be ran and shown when executed.

In the past, we used to use RS.Execute to call these functions and after the call, the returned html would show up on the page. Since we have switched to pagemethods so that the application works in multiple browsers, how can get the returned html to populate in the page in the success function? Thank you for your help.

code example

here is the pagemethod call inside one of my java script functions

```
PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0,0, onSuccess, onFail);
```

this works, as I am able to trace the server side function and see the function being hit - you shouldn't need more of a code example besides that LoadChild returns a string - which is actually html text. My issue is what needs to be placed in the onSuccess Javascript function so that the returned text from LoadChild can be placed on the page so that the new div and table row (which are what the html returned text represents) show up instantly on the page with our reloading.

Comment: please post a code sample so we can see what you're doing

Comment: more information has been added. i can assure you that my pagemethod call works since i am able to use tracepoints to see it is being fully called, its just the string that is returned, needs to be placed on the page as html text so the next row of the table shows up with out refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have on your page:

```
<div id="myResult"></div>
```

Then your onSuccess script function is simply:

```
function onSuccess(args) {
    document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = args;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will look into this method and report back. This should do it, I just need to fix one thing first before I can try this. Thanks again.